# Bootstrap 4 (v4.0.0-alpha.6) - Carousel slides a little extra

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I´m using Bootstrap 4 for a project and I noticed the the carousel slide has an odd behaviour.

When a slide shifts, the slide effect is first fast, but in the end of the slide animation the slide moves very slowly sideways before it finally stops.

For example this is visible in the Bootstrap 4 official example:
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/

I want to remove the slow extra slide effect or slide bug.

Anyone have a clue how to remove this ugly behaviour?

Comment: I happen to like the extra slide.

Comment: It looks ok on small carousels, but on full screen slideshows it is not so nice. Anyone?